# How to get the address of validation?

Tags: vba, excel

There are some validated cells. I should check that a cells has validation or not. If it has validation i should get the range of its validation.
Are there any method for it?
I'ce tried a lot of formulas but it was unsuccessfull.

```
Sub checkForValidation()
Dim cell As Range, v As Long
adatOszlop = 9
todoszamlalo = 0
celOszlop = 15
Set lista = Sheets("Munka1").Range("R:R")

    lista.Name = "Szamok"
    For szamlalo = 4 To 25
        v = 0
        On Error Resume Next

        v = Cells(szamlalo, celOszlop).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeSameValidation).Count
        On Error GoTo 0

        If v = 0 Then
            Debug.Print "No validation"
            Cells(szamlalo, 10) = "No validation"
        Else
            Debug.Print "Has validation"
            Cells(szamlalo, 10) = "Has validation"

                If Not lista.Find(Cells(szamlalo, adatOszlop).Value) Is Nothing Then
                    Dim rng As Range
                    Dim ws As Worksheet

                    Sheets("Munka1").Cells(szamlalo, 14) = "ok"
                    Sheets("Munka1").Cells(szamlalo, celOszlop) = Cells(szamlalo, adatOszlop).Value
                Else
                     Call selectsub(Cells(szamlalo, adatOszlop).Value)
                End If
        End If
    Next
    'End
End Su
```

b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This little sub tests the active cell and gives the range of the *DV* list or lists the *DV* items or tells you there is no *DV*:

```
Sub IsIt()
    On Error GoTo trap
        MsgBox ActiveCell.Validation.Formula1
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
trap:
    MsgBox "no data validation"
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: And how can i give the value of the ActiveCell.Validation.Formula1 to a variable ( range variable )?